# Extract words from sentence in python

Tags: python, nltk

I have a dataset in a text/csv file format. It has 2 columns like this =

```
ID - TEXT
1 - this probability is 10-15% 
2 - approximately 20% probablity 
3 - 15% probability
```

I am trying to use NLTK to extract the number from the data where there is the keyword `'Probability'` present.

This is what my code looks like.

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk
from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize

data_file = pd.read_excel(r'data_excel.xlsx',sheet_name = 'data')

df = pd.DataFrame(data_file, columns = ['ID','TEXT'])
keywords = ["probability"]

id_text = nltk.Text(str(df.ID).splitlines()) 
text_value = nltk.Text(str(df.TEXT).splitlines())
```

I want the output to look like this -

```
ID - Value 
1 - 10
2 - 20
3 - 15
```

If someone can nudge in the right direction, it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

THIS CODE SHOULD WORK OR AT LEAST POINT YOU INTO SOLVING IT
**Here is the full code**

```
import csv
import nltk
impor re
import pandas as pd
from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize

tweet = []

data_file = pd.read_excel(r'data_excel.xlsx',sheet_name = 'data')
df = pd.DataFrame(data_file, columns = ['ID','TEXT'])


cols = ['ID', 'Num']
newDataFrame = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)


#this should provide you with a list of both ID and txt
ID = df.iloc[:,0].values
TEXT  = df.iloc[:,1].values


#loop throug the id and set occurence of the number of probability
for i in range(1, len(ID)):
    number_list = re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', TEXT[i])

    newDataFrame.iloc[i].ID = ID
    newDataFrame.iloc[i].Num = number_list

print(newDataFrame)
```

Comment: thanks man..@sodimu-segun-michael  that helped... i am getting a error though.. for newDataFrame.iloc[i].ID = ID   , its saying single positional indexer is out of bounds

Comment: The code are untested codes and I am not on PC to test it.. Just find a simple way to add  records to dataframe via loop.. That's what the error is about..maybe I missed something small there. Don't forget to mark it as answer if it helped